# Proving that $o(AB)=|A||B|$, where $A,B$ are subgroups with relative prime orders of an abelian group $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $\displaystyle G$ be an Abelian group and let $\displaystyle A$ and $\displaystyle B$ be two subgroups with orders $\displaystyle m$ and $\displaystyle n$ respectively such that $\displaystyle m< n\ $and $\displaystyle \gcd( m,n) =1$. Then it is to be proven that $\displaystyle o( AB) =|A||B|$, where $\displaystyle |X|\ $represents cardinality of the set $\displaystyle X$.

I have already proven that $\displaystyle G$ is abelian $\displaystyle \Longrightarrow AB$ is a subgroup and also proven (refer **note**) that
\begin{equation}
o( AB) =\frac{|A||B|}{|A\cap B|} \tag{1}
\end{equation}

I understand that in the current case, $\displaystyle o( AB) =|A||B|\ $easily follows using Lagrange's theorem but I am not allowed to use Lagrange's theorem, Cauchy's theorem, isomorphisms, concept of order of an element of a group.

So here's what I tried:

Let $\displaystyle |A\cap B|=r$, where $\displaystyle 1\leq r\leq m$. We must prove that $\displaystyle r=1$.

Suppose on the contrary that $\displaystyle r\neq 1$ and therefore $\displaystyle 2\leq r\leq m$.

Now I plan to use induction on $\displaystyle r$.

Base case: $\displaystyle r=2$

Either $\displaystyle ( r\nmid m$ and $\displaystyle r\mid n$) or $\displaystyle ( r\mid m$ and $\displaystyle r\nmid n)$.

I don't know how to proceed from here. I'll appreciate any help in this. Thanks.

> **Note:** Let $\displaystyle G$ be an Abelian group and $\displaystyle A$ and
> $\displaystyle B$ be its two finite subgroups.
>
> I want to prove that the order of $\displaystyle AB=\{ab:a\in A,b\in
> B\}$ is $\displaystyle \frac{|A||B|}{|A\cap B|}$, where $\displaystyle
> |\ X|$ means cardinality of set $\displaystyle X$. I'll use this
> notation $\displaystyle o( S)$ to represent order of group
> $\displaystyle S$.
>
> I will not use Lagrange's theorem, Cauchy theorem, Cosets,isomorphisms
> etc.
>
> It can be shown that $\displaystyle AB$ is a subgroup as
> $\displaystyle G$ is abelian. Clearly $\displaystyle o( AB)$ may not
> necessarily equal to $\displaystyle |AB|$ due to duplication of some
> elements in $\displaystyle AB$.
>
> If $\displaystyle a_{1} b_{1} =a_{2} b_{2}$ then $\displaystyle
>  a_{1}^{-1} a_{2} =b_{1} b_{2}^{-1} \in A\cap B$. It follows that every
> element in $\displaystyle AB$ can duplicate at most $\displaystyle
> |A\cap B|$ times.
>
> Now if $\displaystyle t\in A\cap B$, then for any $\displaystyle ab\in
> AB$, we have $\displaystyle ab=( at)\left( t^{-1} b\right)$, where
> $\displaystyle at\in A$ and $\displaystyle t^{-1} b\in B$.
>
> It follows that every $\displaystyle ab\in AB$ can duplicate at least
> $\displaystyle |A\cap B|$ times.
>
> So every $\displaystyle ab\in G$ can duplicate atleast $\displaystyle
> |A\cap B|$ times and atmost $\displaystyle |A\cap B|$ times and
> therefore every $\displaystyle ab\in AB$ will duplicate exactly
> $\displaystyle |A\cap B|$ times and therefore $\displaystyle |A\cap
>  B|\ o( AB) =|AB|\Longrightarrow o( AB) =\frac{|AB|}{|A\cap B|}$ and we
> are done.

Comment: There's quite a lot you can't use. Why are these restrictions the way they are?

Comment: @jMdA: It’s an exercise problem. Till that chapter, Lagrange’s Theorem or even concept of order of an element of a group have not been introduced :). I strongly believe it is doable because probably that’s why abelian G condition has been given.

Comment: Is $o(AB)$ just $|AB|$?

Comment: @Randall: No. o(X) is order of group $X$ and |Y| is cardinality of set Y.

Comment: @Koro  That is the same thing.

Comment: @Randall: I write o(AB) to emphasise that AB is a (sub)group. AB may not always be a subgroup in which case I denote cardinality by |AB|. I suppose that this convention is not universal? In this case, G being abelian ensures that AB is also a subgroup. That’s all.

Answer (score 1):

Take $A\cap B$ and consider all the sets of the form $a \times A \cap B$ for all $a\in A$, these sets cover all of $A$.

You can prove these sets are disjoint by taking an element $x \in (a* A\cap B) \cap (a'*A\cap B)$. Then $a^{-1}x \in A\cap B$ and $a'^{-1}x \in A\cap B$, so $a^{-1}x (a'^{-1}x)^{-1} = a^{-1} a' \in A\cap B$. So that each element of the form $ag$ for $g\in A\cap B$ is also of the form $a'h$ for $h\in A\cap B$ where $g=a^{-1}a'h$. This proves that if two sets of the form $a*A\cap B$ intersect, they have to be equal.

These sets also have the same cardinality, because $ag=ah$ implies $g=h$, so $|a*A\cap B| = |A\cap B|$.

This means that $m = |A| = \sum_{a*A\cap B} |a*A\cap B| = q |A\cap B|$. So $|A\cap B|$ divides $m$. By the same logic $|A\cap B|$ divides $n$, therefor $|A\cap B|$ divides the $\gcd(n, m) = 1$, so $|A\cap B| = 1$.

This is essentially a proof of Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: This is good actually. +1 Cosets have been introduced secretly:).  So like we do for proving Lagrange’s: we partition given finite group by cosets which are pairwise disjoint ( that is like equivalent classes) . But I think that there’s possibly a way forward from where I got stuck while using induction.